# How to set category array list set single text name

Tags: java, android, arrays

How to set array list category name text. I tried it and I am getting an error. I don't know how to fix this error:

> **`((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_post1)).setText(list.category_name);`** `list.category_name`

The error is being thrown to me how to solve error see image below:

[image: image description here]

```
private void displaypost1(List<Recipe> list) {

    ((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_post1)).setText(list.category_name);



    RecyclerView recyclerView = root_view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_post1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    Adapterpost1 adapterpost1 = new Adapterpost1(getActivity(), recyclerView, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterpost1);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    adapterpost1.setOnItemClickListener((view, obj, position) -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityRecipeDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC, obj);

        startActivity(intent);
        ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).showInterstitialAd();
    });

    LinearLayout lyt_recipes = root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_recipes);
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        lyt_recipes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        lyt_recipes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

```json
"post1": [
    {
      "recipe_id": 91,
      "recipe_title": "விமானப்படை தளபதிகள் (AIR CHIEF MARSHALS)",
      "cat_id": 20,
      "recipe_time": 1,
      "recipe_image": "1643537721_post-88.png",
      "recipe_description": "<p></p>\r\n",
      "video_url": "",
      "video_id": "cda11up",
      "content_type": "Post",
      "featured": 0,
      "tags": 0,
      "total_views": 2209,
      "category_name": "TNPSC-Materials"
    },
    {
      "recipe_id": 90,
      "recipe_title": "இந்தியாவின் தலைமை நீதிபதிகள்",
      "cat_id": 20,
      "recipe_time": 1,
      "recipe_image": "1643537661_post-87.png",
      "recipe_description": "<p></p>\r\n",
      "video_url": "",
      "video_id": "cda11up",
      "content_type": "Post",
      "featured": 0,
      "tags": 0,
      "total_views": 1163,
      "category_name": "TNPSC-Materials"
    },
    {
      "recipe_id": 89,
      "recipe_title": "இந்தியாவின் தலைமை தேர்தல் ஆணையர்கள்",
      "cat_id": 20,
      "recipe_time": 1,
      "recipe_image": "1643537571_post-86.png",
      "recipe_description": "<p></p>\r\n",
      "video_url": "",
      "video_id": "cda11up",
      "content_type": "Post",
      "featured": 0,
      "tags": 0,
      "total_views": 447,
      "category_name": "TNPSC-Materials"
    }
  ],
```

Category array list set single text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are direct access property of DataClass `Recipe` from list.
First You have to get DataClass `Recipe` from specific position of list `List<Recipe>` then you can access `category_name` property.

```
Recipe recipe = list.get(0)
String categoryName = recipe.category_name
```

now you can access `categoryName` for setText OR you can also set like this

```
((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_post1)).setText(recipe.category_name);
```

Hope it'll help to you